# How can I make my countif in Vba match just the month of my tables date column

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to get vba to do some filtered counting when the values of a stored range’s column match the month and the year of a stored date.

I’ve got this below, I know I can’t apply the month function to column(1) because it’s asking for a range. I’ve tried different variations of matching columns(1) and columns(3) to the month and year but haven’t found anything that works yet.

```
Public function(numcount(ByRef RDate As Date, Tal As range)

Counter =0
For i = 1 To tbl.rows.count
   If Month(tbl.cells(I,1).value) = month(RDate) and year(tbl.cells(I,1).value) = year(RDate) and tbl.cells(I,3) =“New” then
If worksheetfunction.countifts(tbl.columns(1) = month(Rdate), tbl.columns(1) = year(Rdate), tbl.columns(3), “New”, tbl.columns(11) tbl,cells(I,11) > 0 Then counter = counter + 1
End if
Next
End if
Numcount = counter
End function
```

Comment: This code as it is doesn't compile - not sure if it's bad typing or something else as there are several issues. Maybe get it to the point where the code runs but fails and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
Took the month and year from the date and just checked if the date was between those two.

```
Countifs(Tbl.columns(1), “>=“& DateSerial(Year(Rdate), Month(Rdate), 1), tbl.columns(1), “<=“ & rdate, tbl.columns(1), …
```

Worked for me after forcing `rdate` to the end of the month earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Count Matches of Months in a Range of Dates (UDF)

```vb
Function MatchMonthsCount( _
    ByVal MatchRange As Range, _
    ByVal MatchDate As Date, _
    Optional ByVal CheckYear As Boolean = True) _
As Long

    Dim cell As Range, CellValue, mCount As Long, IsEqual As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In MatchRange.Cells
        CellValue = cell.Value
        If VarType(CellValue) = vbDate Then
            If Month(CellValue) = Month(MatchDate) Then
                If CheckYear Then
                    If Year(CellValue) = Year(MatchDate) Then IsEqual = True
                Else
                    IsEqual = True
                End If
            End If
            If IsEqual Then IsEqual = False: mCount = mCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    MatchMonthsCount = mCount

End Function
```